# Vertical align an image on iPhone 5 and 6 auto-layout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I want to align an UIImage proportionally on iPhone 5 and 6. If I add a "Top Space to Top Layout guide" to a 20px constant, the spacing is always set to 20px on both devices. I am expecting if it's 20px on iPhone 5, then it should be > 20px on iPhone 6.

I have a full-screen background image and I'm trying to align this UIImage relative to certain items in the background image.

I'll be happy to provide more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Ever thought of finding out what the dimensions of the window is at run time and then adjusting the relevant constraint to position the image where you want?

Comment: @Abizern I have, but I would like to think that there is an easy way using Auto-Layout.

Comment: That is using autolayout.

Comment: I meant at design-time. There is an aspect-ratio constraint for views, I wish there was something like that for spacing. Perhaps there is, but I just don't know and thats what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Think about this for a second; An iPhone5 has a height of 568 points. and iPhone 6 has 667 points, and a 6+ has 736. So, if you wanted to keep things in proportion, 20 points on an iPhone 5 is 23.4859 points on an iPhone 6 and 25.9155 on an iPhone 6+. If you want to keep the same scales, you aren't going to be on point boundaries, and things will be blurred. You're probably better off changing the background image and positioning things based on that. Which you can do with autolayout.

Comment: @pshah how you solved this?